# How do we know the universe is still expanding?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, observable-universe

We know the expansion of the universe has been occurring due to the red shift of light from neighbouring light sources.

But given that light takes time to reach our telescopes, the glimpse of our view of the universe is a snapshot of what occurred x light years in the past, and we therefore do not have a present day representation of our universe. Rather, we only see what once was present, only until now reaching Earth's telescopes.

Given all this, how do we know that the universe is **still** expanding.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that Sun is still there when you look at it in some concrete moment of time, given that photons from Sun reaches your eyes only after 8 minutes? Answer is - You don't. You don't have even a single bit of information about the present state of any object in a universe (including your foot), because it takes time for information to reach observer. Second point is that "now" is a bit obscure term, cause it implies exact location of event. "now" of your head is different than "now" of your foot. Lastly science and creatures in general operates in the sea of recorded past events.

Comment: Thanks for this insight Agnius. The argument regarding the sun was an interesting thought experiment to this question.

Comment: I suggest that you give the meaning  of the word "know" some thought. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/know For the purpose if this discussion, you probably want a part of definition 2a: to be certain of. What kinds if ideas can you be certain of? I suggest that the only kinds are mathematical, for example: 2+2=4. For all other kinds you can have a high confidence level, but not 100% certainty.